# Android Developer - Signing Key Expires

Tags: android

I don't remember what expiration date I've used to sign my apps and I am thinking what will happen when that expiration date will come. Will those apps still be available in Google Play?

Is there any way to find out what expiration date I've used to my private key?

More than that, am I able to simply extend the expiration date ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I would not be too concerned about it. If you follow the instructions on the Android developer guide, you get a key with a very long expiration time. Furthermore, you must have a key of at least 25 years. Here is the snippet from [Signing Your Application](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> If you plan to publish your application(s) on Google Play, note that a
>   validity period ending after 22 October 2033 is a requirement. You can
>   not upload an application if it is signed with a key whose validity
>   expires before that date.

If you really want to see your key's expiration time though, you can use keytool:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my.keystore
```

Comment: Indeed, the key is for at least 25 years I don't doubt about that however I'm interested what will happen in 25 years. I will still be able to extend that expiration date to my certificate? will my apps be removed at that time?

Comment: You just won't be able to update it anymore. But that's not a problem. In 25 years nobody will be using your app anymore (no offense)

Comment: Probably, however I'm signing my apps with the same key created 2 yeara ago. So I'd better create a new key which will expire in 100 years better right? There is definitely not any solution to modify an existing key and extend it and still use it for previous apps signed with it?

Comment: I would think the 25 year limit will kick in and it won't accept that key soon for new apps. I'm sure on October 2033, Google will supply a migration path for people who are somehow in that situation.

Comment: I believe that too that Google should find a solution for people ib that situation, there will be thousand apps or even ten thousand which will be removed due that expiration issue

Comment: I dont think apps will be removed. You just won't be able to update them. For the 99.99% of apps I think that will be just fine, in 2033 they won't be relevant or maintained anymore.

Comment: Yes but as known so far, you won't be able to install a specific app if it's certificate is expired, maybe Google will modify that who knows

Comment: It's ok if the apps will still be available even you won't be able to update them. I've tried the command you've wrote but I have 2 files, a certificate.pem and key.pk8. Am I missing something?

Comment: So I'd better create a new key which will expire in 100 years or continue using the initial key?

Comment: The command should be run on the .pem file. You can't switch to another key for apps you've already published - for new apps, you could switch to another key that expires further out. I actually use a different key for each app, in case one gets compromised, it only affects that one app.

Comment: I've found using openssl x509 -in tempcrt.pem -noout -enddate 

It expires in 2039

Comment: That's fine, I'm sure the technology will be different however I'm thinking what will happen with the apps in 2033 when the first apls wilk have their certificate expired. Will be removed? That's strange, at least those apps should be able to be purchased and installed after that date too

Comment: @GregEnnis that's what I thought when I first publish my application and set the expiry date to year 2020, stupid, I know. Right now I not only kept outside from google play store, but also have to ask my users to uninstall the previous version and install new version of our application when it comes to 2020.